# Change the size of checkbox rectangle without changing its content

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

In my following `WPF` app, how can we change the size of the `CheckBox` **without** changing the size of its content (an [Segoe MDL2 Assets icon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/segoe-ui-symbol-font)). I would like to see the checkbox rectangle to be the half the size of its content (an icon). If I set the width and height of the checkbox to 10 it reduces the content size (icon) as well:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="10">
            <Label FontWeight="Bold">Application Options</Label>
            <CheckBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="&#xE715;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="20"/>
            </CheckBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Display of the above XAML**:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the `TextBlock` out of the `CheckBox`. Something like this:

```
<StackPanel Margin="10">
    <Label FontWeight="Bold">Application Options</Label>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CheckBox RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <CheckBox.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
            </CheckBox.RenderTransform>
        </CheckBox>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="&#xE715;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="20"/>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

[image]